# what is the max size of a string type in terraform

Tags: string, terraform, size, limit

I'm trying to locate a definitive answer to, "What is the max size of a Terraform value type of 'string'"?

Been searching and googling and can't seem to find it defined anywhere.  Anyone have any reference they could point me to?

Tia
Bill W

Comment: Why? Do you get any errors regarding the length of your strings?

Comment: No, I was asked by a colleague.  Most languages specify the max string size but Terraform apparently doesn't--at least I haven't found it anywhere yet.

Comment: " Most languages specify the max string size" do they?

Answer (score 0):

The length of strings in Terraform is constrained in two main ways:

- Terraform internally tracks the length of the string, which is stored as an integer type which has a limited range.
- Strings need to exist in system memory as a consecutive sequence of bytes.

The first of these is directly answerable: Terraform tracks the length of a string using an integer type large enough to represent all pointers on the host platform. From a practical standpoint then, that means a 64-bit integer when you're using a 64-bit build, and a 32-bit number when you're using a 32-bit build.

That means that there's a hard upper limit imposed by the maximum value of that integer. Terraform is internally tracking the length of the UTF-8 representation of the string in bytes, and so this upper limit is measured in bytes rather than in characters:

- 32-bit systems: 4,294,967,295 bytes
- 64-bit systems: 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 bytes

Terraform stores strings in memory using [Unicode NFC normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normalization), UTF-8 encoded, and so the number of *characters* will vary depending on how many bytes each character takes up in the UTF-8 encoding form. ASCII characters take only one byte, but other characters can require up to four bytes.

A string of the maximum representable length would take up the entire address space of the Terraform process, which is impossible (there needs to be room for the Terraform application code, libraries, and kernel space too!), and so in practice the available memory on your system is the more relevant limit. That limit varies based on various characteristics of the system where you're running Terraform, and so isn't answerable in a general sense.